# integrating: $\sqrt{1+4x^{2}+4x^{4}}$ on the interval [0,1]

Tags: calculus, integration

so far i've tried to use substitution with $u = x^{2}$ but this didn't make my integral easier to calculate. i don't see how i can use partial integration either so i get kind of stuck.

Wolfram alpha tells me the answer of this integral is $\frac{5}{3}$ which is a nice answer.

I think that i need to choose a very smart substitution in the triogonometry but i don't see which one,

Any tips/tricks?

Kees

Comment: $1+4x^2+4x^4 = (1+2x^2)^2$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note that 
$$1+4x^2+4x^4=(2x^2+1)^2.$$
Since 
$$2x^2+1\gt0,$$
you'll have
$$\sqrt{1+4x^2+4x^4}=\sqrt{(2x^2+1)^2}=2x^2+1.$$

Comment: tx this helps a lot

Comment: You are welcome!